# PHP - Wrap multiple instances with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
'<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg">
<img src="image4.jpg"><img src="image5.jpg">'
```

I'd like to come to:

```
'<div class="slide"><img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>     
<div class="slide"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="image3.jpg"></div>'
```

**So basically I'd like to apply a preg_replace to wrap every 2 elements in a DIV.**

I searched the forum and found some tips that I tried:

```
$pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)+/i';
$replacement = '<div class="slide">$1</div>';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

and

```
$pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>){2,}/i';
$replacement = '<div class="slide">$1</div>';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

But it doesn't work...

Any idea, guys?

Thank you!

Comment: Try like [this demo](https://eval.in/602357).

Answer (score 2):

Use DomDocumen object to do it:

```
$str = '<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg">
<img src="image4.jpg"><img src="image5.jpg">'; 
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

$i = $imgs->length;
$cur = 0;
$res = new DomDocument;

while ($i >= 2) {
   $div = $res->createElement('div');
   $div->setAttribute("class","slide"); 
   $res->appendChild($div);
   $div->appendChild($res->importNode($imgs->item($cur++)));
   $div->appendChild($res->importNode($imgs->item($cur++)));
   $i -= 2;   
}
if($i)  $res->appendChild($res->importNode($imgs->item($cur++)));

echo $res->saveHTML();

// <div class="slide"><img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"></div><div class="slide"><img src="image3.jpg"><img src="image4.jpg"></div><img src="image5.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example:

```
<?php

$content = '<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg">
<img src="image3.jpg"><img src="image4.jpg">
<img src="image5.jpg">';

$pattern = '/((<img[^>]*src=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>\s*){2,2})/i';
$replacement = '<div class="slide">$1</div>';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

echo $content;
```

It is your second example, but with 4 fixes:

1. `class` -> `src`
2. added block () to catch 2 items
3. fixed quantity {2,} -> {2,2} (change it to {1,2} if you want to catch last one `img` tag)
4. `\s*` added to catch spaces and line breaks between img tags

Comment: Thank you much, it works!

But as it only works every 2 items, the 5th picture isn't wrapped in a div.
I'd rather like it to come to:
`<div class="slide"><img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"></div>     
    <div class="slide"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="image3.jpg"></div>`

So I'm wondering if preg_replace is a good solution...

Comment: if you'll change {2,2} to {1,2} then it should work as you expected.